# Modify floor/ceiling function to work with numbers other than 1?

Tags: javascript

By default the floor function always rounds down and the ceil function always rounds up to the nearest '1'

How would I round down/up to the nearest 20, or the nearest 1,000?

Say I had a number x and a factor y.

I want to find the closest factor of y to x.

I am using this to find maximum and minimum values for a graph. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple:

```
var z = y * Math.floor(x / y);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Math.floor(x / 20) * 20;
Math.ceil(x / 20) * 20;
```

In your case:

```
Math.floor(x / y) * y;
```

The `x / y` turns the expression into `units of y`; with `.floor()` or `.ceil()` you then round it down or up; afterwards you multiply with `y` again to get your final answer.